# How to solve the ambipolar transport equation in semicondutor？

Tags: semiconductor-physics

> The one-dimensional ambipolar transport equation for the minority carrier holes can be written from Equation (6.56) as $$ D_p\frac{\partial^2\left(\delta p\right)}{\partial x^2}-\mu_pE_0\frac{\partial\left(\delta p\right)}{\partial x}-\frac{\delta p}{\tau_{p0}}=\frac{\partial\left(\delta p\right)}{\partial t}\tag{6.66}$$The solution to this partial differential equation is of the form $$\delta p\left(x,\,t\right)=p'\left(x,\,t\right)\mathrm{e}^{-t/\tau_{p0}}\tag{6.67}$$ By substituting Equation (6.67) into Equation (6.66), we are left with the partial differential equation
> $$D_p\frac{\partial^2p'\left(x,\,t\right)}{\partial x^2}-\mu_pE_0\frac{\partial p'\left(x,\,t\right)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial p'\left(x,\,t\right)}{\partial t}\tag{6.68}$$

Why does the solution of the Equation (6.66) have the form of Equation (6.67)?

Comment: Can you specify which quantities ($D_p$, $\mu_p$, etc.) are time and/or position dependent, and in what way (for example they might be proportional to $\frac{1}{x^2}$).

Comment: It might also be useful for future readers if you included the source of this quote (the author(s) and title of the text should be sufficient).

Comment: Hi,Dp,  μp,E0,τp0 are all constants,thank you@tonetillo 4

Comment: Semiconductor physics and devices basic principles 4th by Neamen,Chapter 6@Kyle Kanos,thank you